# Image size/width after appending not available immediately

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, dom, image-size

I am currently writing a jQuery plugin where images are cloned and then inserted into the DOM. The problem I am facing is that even though the images are cloned (and therefore already cached, as I am executing this code on `window.load`) it takes a short while for width() and height() to become available after appending them to the DOM. The script is much too long to post here, but in general I am doing this:

```
var clone = $(el).clone(); //el is some container containing one or more images
$(someElementInDOM).append(clone);

clone.find("img").each(function() {
    console.log("height: "+$(this).height()+", width: "+$(this).width());
});
```

This gives me 0 for width and height. If I wait a short while before executing the console.log the width and height are available, though. I know about the `load` event for images, but I cannot use that as I heavily depend on my code being executed synchronously (because the order in which the elements are inserted into the DOM is crucial). Since it seems impossible to execute the `load` event synchronously, I wonder what to do here. I am not even sure why this behaviour is occuring, in my opinion a downloaded image should have width and height attached instantly after appending it to the DOM?

Thanks!

Comment: I think it is because the images are not cached and because of that the image elements in the cloned part doesnot have the image loaded to find the size

Comment: It must be like this, but I don't understand why. The original `el` is in the DOM and all images inside it have been loaded, I make sure of that.